# C++ Application - SQL database replication broadcasting events

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, networking, triggers

before asking the actual question I will briefly explain my current situation:

I have a C++ application written using the Qt framework, the application itself runs on a network and several instances of the same application can live on different machines, they will all reflect the same data in the common shared database.

In this application I have several UIs and other internal processes that need to be aware when changes happen to the database (Sql Server 2012). But they don't watch the database so they need to be told when something changes. So the way it works now is that whenever in once instance of the application I execute a Stored procedure in the database, I also create an xml based event that is being broadcast to all other applications instances. Once they receive this event they will update the corresponding UI or start the internal processing they need to do.

I'm working to extend this application to be cross systems which means that I want another network somewhere else, which is running another database which should be identical, and so changes on a database in the first network needs to be mirrored in the database in the second network. Whenever this happens I want the same events to be fired under the second network so all UIs and internal processing can start in the second system.

My solution so far is to use SQL Server replication tool. This seems very nice for synchronizing the two databases (and admittedly seems quite smooth as a solution) but the problem that I am facing now is that the other system, where the database is being synchronized, will not have the events fired. This is because the changes to the database does not happen through the application code so no-one on the second network is creating the xml based event and so none of the application instances on the second network will know the database has changed.

The solution that I've been thinking for this problem is to add *triggers* to each table so when that table changes I will populate another table that one application instance will watch by polling it periodically (every second let's say) and every time a change happens to that table I will create the xml event and broadcast in the network.

**Questions:** is my solution maintainable over time? Are triggers really the only way to achieve what I want? (Fire events in the synchronized system network) Is there some other way (possibly sql server built-in solution) to get updates from the database in a C++ application when something changes so I don't have to use triggers and watch tables populated by them?

Comment: The info [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4464/automate-sql-server-replication-monitoring/) details an alternative solution. It automates replication monitoring by sending replication status notifications to a central monitoring server.